# single activity recyclerview for two button

Tags: android, android-studio, button, android-recyclerview

I created a player list program, now according to the program I created, there is a button (at start_activity) when the program starts. clicking on this button will open a list created by the next "recyclerview". I have a question about how to put two buttons (to "start_activity") ("new stars" and "historical stars") and connect both to one recyclerview, the list design will be the same for both, only the names in the list will change . is it possible to use the same recyclerview for both to make it much simpler? how please show an example from the code. Thank you.

Comment: yes it is possible, but we can't code for you. You need to show what are the things you tried and we can then suggest improvements on that.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.

On first button click - get your list data & set an adapter in a recyclerview.

On second button click - get your other list data & set an adapter in the same recyclerview.

So your data will be updated. You just have to initialize new data & adapter on button click, then set adapter in the recyclerview.